# Transporting data to create a new data frame to re-structure the data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transform, transport

I have a csv file that contains data along the rows.
I want to create a data frame by transporting all rows to columns.I have provided the following sample data frame that replicates the data in csv.

```
data = pd.DataFrame()
data ['Name'] = ['A','B','C']
data ['Home'] = ['Z','Y','X']
data ['1-0'] = [2.2,3.1,3]
data['2-0'] = [1.5,5,8]
data ['2-1'] = [5,2,3]
data ['HW'] = [1.2,3.2,4]
```

I want to convert the columns '1-0','2-0','2-1' to a column of a new data frame and its corresponding data to a new columns says **Score**.
The first column ** Name** will be used as a new column but duplicates for all score.

The following is the expected output.

[image]

In the new data frame, the element from first column **Name** will be duplicated. The elements in the second column **Score** is some of the columns name from old data frame.
The rest columns such as **HW** will be duplicated as the same as the name column.

May I know how to transform it?
Your advice is much appreciated.
Thanks.
Zep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `melt`:

```
data.melt(['Name','Home','HW']).sort_values('Name')
```

Output:

```
  Name Home   HW variable  value
0    A    Z  1.2      1-0    2.2
3    A    Z  1.2      2-0    1.5
6    A    Z  1.2      2-1    5.0
1    B    Y  3.2      1-0    3.1
4    B    Y  3.2      2-0    5.0
7    B    Y  3.2      2-1    2.0
2    C    X  4.0      1-0    3.0
5    C    X  4.0      2-0    8.0
8    C    X  4.0      2-1    3.0
```

---

Also,you can use `set_index` and `stack`:

```
data.set_index(['Name','Home','HW']).stack().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  Name Home   HW variable  value
0    A    Z  1.2      1-0    2.2
3    A    Z  1.2      2-0    1.5
6    A    Z  1.2      2-1    5.0
1    B    Y  3.2      1-0    3.1
4    B    Y  3.2      2-0    5.0
7    B    Y  3.2      2-1    2.0
2    C    X  4.0      1-0    3.0
5    C    X  4.0      2-0    8.0
8    C    X  4.0      2-1    3.0
```